# How to create a TBL using standard evaluation data_frame_ function?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a dataframe using strings for column names (using the `data_frame_` function)

```
colName <- "y"
x <- 1

> data_frame(x = x, y = 2)
Source: local data frame [1 x 2]

   x y
 1 1 2
```

I would like to get the same result than above but using the `colName` object as the 2nd column name.

So I think this is what `data_frame_` is for but I don't know how to make it work.

columns should be a lazy_dots, but how can I eval a function argument's name :

```
data_frame_(lazyeval::lazy_dots(x = x, colName = 2))
```

Do you have any ideas ? Thank

Answer (score 0):

Just for the completeness (using Hadley's comment):

```
colName <- "y"
x <- 1
data_frame_(setNames(lazyeval::lazy_dots(x, 2), c("x", "y")))

# A tibble: 1 x 2
      x     y
    <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2
```